# Postgres: match pattern after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to group all rows by `foo` when at least one row in a group matches `bar='baz'`.

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT foo, string_agg(bar) 
FROM table 
WHERE bar='baz' 
GROUP BY foo;
```

However, this obviously leaves out rows where `bar!=baz`. 
I want to include those rows if at least one in the group matches. 
What's the best way to achieve this?

I have considered using a sub-selection using array_agg(bar) and ANY, for example:

```
SELECT foo, bars FROM (
    SELECT foo, array_agg(bar) as bars
    FROM table
    WHERE 'baz' ANY(bars)
    GROUP BY FOO
)
```

But this seems like an ugly solution and also doesn't let me use string_agg.

Comment: would you please add data sample and expected result?..

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT foo, string_agg(bar) 
FROM table 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM table t WHERE t.bar='baz' AND t.foo = foo)
GROUP BY foo;
```

or `IN` can be useful as well

```
SELECT foo, string_agg(bar) 
FROM table 
WHERE foo IN (SELECT t.foo FROM table t WHERE t.bar='baz')
GROUP BY foo;
```

Comment: Thank you! I suppose there's no way around using a sub-select? My actual query is more complicated, since bar is actually in another table. It looks to me like this solution searches the database twice, making it twice as slow, unless Postgres is doing some kind of caching I don't know about.

Comment: @Agargara I do not see a reason why for example solution with `IN` should significantly slow down the query. If you need a speed-up create an index for the query (having pair `(bar,foo)` as a key).

Comment: Thank you, and you're correct. My slow-down was due to an unrelated problem (adding too many regular expressions.)

Answer (score 1):

Test [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) against @Radim's `exists` answer:

```
select foo, string_agg(bar) 
from t
group by foo
having bool_or(bar = 'baz')
```

Comment: This looks much more elegant and I want to use it...but surprisingly enough in testing it's slower than the exists solution! At least in my particular application the EXISTS query takes ~800ms while bool_or takes ~1200ms.

Comment: @Agargara My guess is that an index on `(foo,bar)` will make both perform the same.